# Remove unused CSS/JS in Fomantic UI (Semantic UI fork)

Tags: angular, gulp, semantic-ui

I use Fomantic UI, an updated version of Semantic UI with Gulp.
I followed the tutorial here : https://fomantic-ui.com/introduction/build-tools.html

Here's my semantic.json file :

```
{
  "base": "semantic/",
  "paths": {
    "source": {
      "config": "src/theme.config",
      "definitions": "src/definitions/",
      "site": "src/site/",
      "themes": "src/themes/"
    },
    "output": {
      "packaged": "dist/",
      "uncompressed": "dist/components/",
      "compressed": "dist/components/",
      "themes": "dist/themes/"
    },
    "clean": "dist/"
  },
  "permission": false,
  "autoInstall": false,
  "rtl": false,
  "version": "2.7.2",
  "components": [
    "reset",
    "site",
    "button",
    "container",
    "divider",
    "header",
    "icon",
    "image",
    "input",
    "label",
    "list",
    "segment",
    "breadcrumb",
    "form",
    "grid",
    "menu",
    "message",
    "table",
    "ad",
    "card",
    "comment",
    "feed",
    "item",
    "accordion",
    "checkbox",
    "dimmer",
    "dropdown",
    "modal",
    "popup",
    "sidebar",
    "visibility"
  ]
}
```

I've restricted my "components" list to fit my needs.
Everytime I make a `gulp build` the semantic.min.css and the semantic.min.js files have the same size (755 Ko for CSS and 338 Ko for JS), even if I remove components in the JSON list.
I don't want to import my CSS and JSS one by one importing the components files...

I've noticed also a strange error : when I remove the two files below in my dist repository, Gulp doesn't create them again. So I think I missed something in the process...

Is someone could help me please ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Fomantic-UI 2.8.2 has got an additional file `variation.variables` where you can set the unwanted component variations to `false` so they don't get compiled reducing the overall generated CSS
Since Fomantic-UI 2.7.0 you can also heavily reduce the generated CSS when adjusting/reducing the needed colors in the central `colors.less` file

Answer (score 0):

For removing unused CSS files, you can install purifyCSS:

```
npm i -D gulp gulp-purifycss
```

For example, In the root of Angular project create `gulpfile.js` and add the following code:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const purify = require('gulp-purifycss');

gulp.task('purifyCSS', () => {
  return gulp
    .src('./dist/*/styles.*.css')
    .pipe(
      purify(['./src/app/**/*.ts', './src/app/**/*.html'], {
        info: true, // Outputs reduction information (like in the screenshot above)
        minify: true, // Minifies the files after reduction
        rejected: false, // Logs the CSS rules that were removed
        whitelist: ['*transition*', '*dimmer*'] // Ignored css classes
      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

After building your web app with:

```
ng build --prod
```

run:

```
npx gulp purifyCSS
```

to remove automatically unused css.